# A random non-poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I encountered this example in a book :

> Buses
>   arrive at a station deterministically, on the hour, and fifteen minutes after the hour.
>   Thus, the interarrival times alternate between $15$ and $45$ minutes. The average
>   interarrival time is $30$ minutes. A person shows up at the bus station at a “random”
>   time. We interpret “random” to mean a time which is uniformly distributed within
>   a particular hour. Such a person falls into an interarrival interval of length $15$ with
>   probability $1/4$, and an interarrival interval of length $45$ with probability $3/4$. The
>   expected value of the length of the chosen interarrival interval is
>   $$15\cdot\frac{1}{4}+45\cdot\frac{3}{4} = 37.5$$
>   which is considerably larger than $30$, the average interarrival time.

This was given in the book after explaining the `random-incidence paradox` . I understand that this example has been given to show that it is counter-intuitive to think that the inter-arrival times and time which a person has to wait on average between two arrival is same.

With reference to the above example in the book , I have a very simple doubt , shouldn't we in the calculation use $7.5$ and $22.5$ instead of $15$ and $45$ , because although the probability of falling in $15$ minute interval is $\frac{1}{4}$ , but once it falls in the $15$ minute interval , on an average the person has to wait $7.5$ minutes ( because the process is uniformly random ) . Please someone guide me through this example .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you are correct about the average waiting time, how ever the book seems to be speaking about "The expected value of the length of the chosen interarrival interval".

Comment: Expected value of the length of the chosen interarrival interval $=2\times$ Expected value of the  waiting time.